# Derivative of $\frac{\cos(y)^4}{x^4}$ using the quotient rule

Tags: calculus

I have to find the derivative of $\frac{\cos(y)^4}{x^4}$ in order of $x$. Using the quotient rule I'm making $$\frac{(\cos(y)^4)'x^4-(x^4)'\cos(y)^4}{x^{4^2}}$$

This gives me $\frac{0-4x^3\cos(y)^4}{x^{16}}\Rightarrow -\frac{4\cos(y)^4}{x^{13}}$ but Wolfram is giving $-\frac{4\cos(y)^4}{x^5}$.

Wolfram is using the power rule as I'm using the quotient rule but nevertheless I believe that the result should be the same so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the numerator is independent of $x$, so you should not use the quotient rule.

Comment: Also, $(x^4)^2 \ne x^{4^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the numerator is independent of $x$, you can use the elementary [power rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule) and obtain

$$\left(\frac{\cos^4{y}}{x^4}\right)'=-4\cdot\frac{\cos^4{y}}{x^5}.$$

However, the quotient rule is still valid, but note that $(x^4)^2=x^8$.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot the parenthesis. So simple...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Note that $$\left(\cos^4(y)\right)'=y'\times 4\times (-\sin(y))\times \cos^3(y)$$ according to the Chain Rule. I assumed that $y=y(x)$ here. And if $y$ and $x$ is independent to each other note that $x^{4^2}\neq x^{16}$ but $x^{{4}^{2}}$ means $(x^4)^2=x^8$.

Comment: Thanks. I've realized what I've done wrong

Comment: Nice work, Babak +1

Answer (score 1):

You have squared the denominator wrong. You should have done

$$(x^4)^2 = x^{2 \times 4} = x^8$$

whereas instead you did

$$x^{(4^2)}$$

which is different.

Comment: Realized my mistake. Thanks